# targetValue, score don't appear in outlets for the view

Tags: ios, xcode

Have been working on single view game, which includes targetValue and score, both of which should appear in the outlets in the view. Connected them to the view controller (File's Owner) in IB, and the targetValue used to appear, but now, after adding some code, it doesn't appear anymore.

What's wrong?

Here is the code from BullseyeViewController.m:

```
#import "BullsEyeViewController.h"

@implementation BullsEyeViewController {
   int currentValue;
   int targetValue;
   int score;
}

@synthesize  slider;
@synthesize targetLabel;
@synthesize scoreLabel;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)updateLabels
{
    self.targetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", targetValue];
    self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
}

- (void)startNewRound
{
    targetValue = 1 + (arc4random() % 100);
    currentValue = self.slider.value;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startNewRound];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.slider = nil;
    self.targetLabel = nil;
    self.scoreLabel = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (IBAction)showAlert
{
    int difference = abs(targetValue - currentValue);
    int points =  100 - difference;
    score += points;

    NSString *title;
    if (difference == 0) {
        title = @"Perfect!";
        points += 100;
    } else if (difference < 5) {
        if (difference == 1) {
        points += 50;
        }   
        title = @"You almost had it!";
    } else if (difference < 10) {
        title = @"Pretty good!";
    } else {
        title = @"Not even close...";
    }


        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d points", points];  



     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:title 
                          message:message
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

     [alertView show]; 


} 

- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider
{
    currentValue = lroundf(slider.value);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set a breakpoint on updateLabels, does it ever hit?

Also, change your `updateLabels` method to look like this:

```
- (void)updateLabels
{
    targetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", targetValue];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
}
```

Do you refer to these labels from outside of your view controller?  If not, do they need to be properties?